# R: How to read a csv file containing non-dataset information

Tags: r, csv, notepad++

I have a .csv file that doesn't show line breaks in notepad. Notepad++ revealed LF characters at the end, but I can't figure out how to tell R to use that character as the line break or how to replace it with CRLF or \n.

**Edit: [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8428744/Collaboration_vs_Publication_Year.csv) is an example file.

Comment: Eventually `fread()` from the package `data.table` can read the file.

Comment: Or you convert the file (normally also a good Editor-program can do) http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/

Comment: I have no problem reading CR, LF, CRLF, or LFCR with `read.csv` on Windows.

Comment: Perhaps provide the code you're using to try to read in your file....

Comment: The code is: file <- read.csv("filename.csv").The file is a small dataset with 9 columns but the first 14 rows have information that is not structured the same way as the data (i.e., in two rows, with white space, etc). Experimenting with it more i discovered that if I skip the first 14 rows it imports the 9 columns correctly, but I'm hoping not to skip those rows. fill=TRUE did not work. I see that read.table has more options that I can experiment with so I will try that too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SarahHailey - edit your question to add a reproducible sample of your data and the error message you received.  From what you've said this is more likely to be an issue with your data structure than any newline character encoding.

Comment: Ok, I added an example file. I didn't receive an error, but the file in R has only two rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using our fast, friendly file finagler:

```
library(data.table)

url <- 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8428744/Collaboration_vs_Publication_Year.csv'

# ignore first 14 rows per OP comment
df <-fread(url, skip = 14) # in this case, it works even without skip=

# put first 14 rows somewhere else
other_stuff <- readLines(url, n=14)
```

> Warning message: In
>   fread("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8428744/Collaboration_vs_Publication_Year.csv")
>   :   Stopped reading at empty line 23 but text exists afterwards
>   (discarded): "Â© 2015 Elsevier B.V. All rights reserved. SciVal Â® is
>   a registered trademark of Reed Elsevier Properties S.A., used under
>   license."

```
df
#                            V1 V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10
# 1:           Brown University NA 0.80 0.84 0.81 0.79 0.79 0.79 0.76 0.64
# 2:        Columbia University NA 0.98 0.96 0.95 0.96 1.00 1.01 0.97 1.26
# 3:         Cornell University NA 0.94 0.92 0.93 0.95 0.93 0.98 0.94 1.26
# 4:          Dartmouth College NA 0.74 0.79 0.70 0.75 0.74 0.75 0.73 0.60
# 5:         Harvard University NA 1.08 1.05 1.06 1.10 1.09 1.10 1.08 0.97
# 6:       Princeton University NA 1.04 0.99 1.02 1.06 1.08 1.05 1.06 0.87
# 7: University of Pennsylvania NA 0.80 0.78 0.79 0.83 0.81 0.80 0.79 0.83
# 8:            Yale University NA 0.93 0.90 0.92 0.95 0.91 0.97 0.90 1.07

cat(other_stuff[nchar(other_stuff)>0], sep = '\n')
# ï»¿Data set,Collaboration vs Publication Year
# Entities,"Brown University, Columbia University, Cornell University, Dartmouth College, Harvard University, Princeton University, University of Pennsylvania, Yale University"
# Year range,2010 to >2015
# Filtered by,"not filtered"
# Data source,Scopus
# Date last updated,16 October 2015
# Date exported,19 November 2015
# Metric name,Specific metric,Self-citations,Types of publications included,Other options
# Collaboration,International collaboration,-,"Articles, reviews and conference papers","field-weighted"
# Name,Tags,Collaboration,
# ,,Overall,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,>2015,
```

Comment: Thanks! That's nifty, but how do I keep the first 14 rows? Ultimately I'd like to parse the first 14 rows and the data set into two different files.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful! If you don't mind explaining, what is fread doing differently than read.csv? It seems like read.csv is guessing that there are 2 columns based on the first rows, and I can't even begin to guess why fread skips all of those rows and neatly returns the 8X10 dataset.

Comment: That is a great question for @MattDowle, but I think your guess is a good one.  I can only point to `?fread: Once the separator is found on line autostart, the number of columns is determined. Then the file is searched backwards from autostart until a row is found that doesn't have that number of columns. Thus, the first data row is found and any human readable banners are automatically skipped. ....` I bet `read.csv` starts with line 1 instead of this flexible autostart.  I'm editing your title to reflect what the problem probably was (i.e., not LF).